# SQL Server Select statement

Tags: sql-server

Each vendor in Vendors table has a pre-assigned [DefaultAccountNo].

Write a SELECT statement with GROUP BY, ORDER BY, and TOP to find five DefaultAccountNo that are assigned to the most vendors. Please include in your answer all DefaultAccountNo if they are associated with the same number of vendors that meet the condition. If any such DefaultAccountNo exists, your answer will contain six or more DefaultAccountNo.

**This is what I have attempted**, But I am not getting the desired output

```
SELECT  TOP 5 with ties DefaultAccountNo, DefaultTermsID, COUNT (*) as 
   VendorsQty
FROM Vendors 
GROUP BY DefaultAccountNo, DefaultTermsID
Having  count(*) >= 5
ORDER BY DefaultAccountNo DESC
```

Comment: We are not going to do your homework for you. And of course we have no sample data to work with anyway so we couldn't possibly help much here.

Comment: Could you provide sample data?

Comment: As Sean said, this looks like a homework or other test question. I would suggest that you reread the question carefully and look at your code; nowhere in the question does it say that the number of vendors for a [DefaultAccountNo] has to be greater than or equal to 5, it says "the most vendors"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (you have use either subquery or CTE):

```
SELECT TOP 5 with ties 
  source.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT DefaultAccountNo, count(distinct VendorId) as VendorsCount
    FROM Vendors 
    GROUP BY DefaultAccountNo
  ) as source
ORDER BY VendorsCount Desc
```